# C# - Unable to invoke Action Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I am not able to invoke a delegate when passing an anonymous function.

Here is the code.

```
public class MethodCollection
{ 
    public static void Print(Action<int, int> printNumbers)
    {

    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodCollection.Print((p, q) => { p = q = 3; Console.WriteLine(p + q); });
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

The output is a blank screen. 
The program does not print the expected output, i.e. 6.

Comment: Your `Print` method has no implementation - you never *do* anything with `printNumbers`.

Comment: (Additionally, it's not clear why you've used an action with parameters when you don't *do* anything with those parameter values.)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `printNumbers.Invoke(3,3);` or so in your Print method.

You should remove the `p = q = 3;` in your action because as Jon mentioned this will make your action ignore the numbers you pass the action.

Comment: Or indeed `printNumbers(0, 0);` given that the initial values of `p` and `q` are ignored...

Answer (score 0):

Or it can be something like this... and I think you should see delegates basics first

[helpful link to learn basics of delegates](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-action-delegate)

```
public class MethodCollection
        {
            public static void Print(Action<int, int> printNumbers)
            {
                printNumbers.Invoke(0,0);
            }
        }

        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                MethodCollection.Print((p, q) => { Console.WriteLine((p=3) + (q=3)); });
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
```